# Best way to make JAWS read an embedded iframe's content

Tags: javascript, html, jaws-screen-reader

I'm trying to change the content of an `iframe` in a webpage and want JAWS screen reader to read only that content.

For this, I have used `jQuery("#vn_space").focus();`

But this doesn't seem to work properly in all browsers. In IE9, JAWS is not reading links as 'links', and in FF, it is not reading the `iframe`'s content at all.

What should I do to make JAWS read the changed content properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the attribute `tabindex` in your HTML? It may be worthwhile to give `aria-label` and `role` a try, too, to see if they help with the issue.